# C | Socket isn't closing correctly

Tags: c, sockets, fork, telnet

I am currently writing a server which is using fork to handle more than 1 connection.

I am testing it via telnet. It is all working fine but telnet doesn't tell me when the connection is closed.

This is my code:

```
int main(void) {
    int pop3socket;
    int clientSocket;
    int len;
    int binden;
    int zuhoeren;
    int schliessen;
    int enable=1;
    int pid;
    int pop3_status;
    int server_running = 1;
    /* Infos ueber die Kommunikationspartner :) */
    struct sockaddr_in mailserver;
    struct sockaddr_in pop3client;

    /* Socket erstellen */
    pop3socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(pop3socket < 0) {
        perror("Fehler beim Erstellen des Sockets!");
    }

    /* IP wiederverwenden */
    if(setsockopt(pop3socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
        perror("Fehler beim Wiederverwenden der IP");
    }

    /* IP und Port festlegen mithilfe von Bind */
    memset(&mailserver, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); 
    mailserver.sin_family = AF_INET;
    mailserver.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    mailserver.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    binden = bind(pop3socket, (struct sockaddr*)&mailserver, sizeof(mailserver));
    if(binden < 0) {

    }

    /* Warteschlange einrichten */
    zuhoeren = listen(pop3socket, 5);
    if(zuhoeren == -1) {
        perror("Fehler beim Listen");
    }

    /* Verbindung(en) akzeptieren */
    for(;;) {
        len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        clientSocket = accept(pop3socket, (struct sockaddr*)&pop3client, &len);

        if(clientSocket < 0) {
            perror("Fehler beim Accepten der Verbindung");
        }

        if( (pid = fork()) < 0) {
            perror("Fork fehlgeschlagen");
            exit(8);
        } else if(pid == 0) {
            close(pop3socket);
            printf("Prozess: %d\n", getpid());
            /* Begruessen */
            sendSuccessMessage("", clientSocket);
            while(server_running == 1) {
                switch( (pop3_status = (process_pop3(clientSocket, clientSocket))) ) {
                    printf("Status: %d\n", pop3_status);
                    case -1: 
                        server_running = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(server_running == 0) {
                printf("Connection beenden\n");
                schliessen = close(clientSocket);
                if(schliessen < 0) {
                    perror("Fehler beim Schließen des Sockets");
                    exit(9);
                }
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems my child process keeps running and does not end properly?
I have absolutely no idea why that is happening.

This is the telnet output:

```
telnet localhost 9999 Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to localhost. Escape character is '^]'.
+OK  user joendhard
+OK  pass test123
+OK User logged in. stat
+OK 9 9735 quit
+OK User logged out.
```

Expected output:

telnet localhost 9999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK 
user joendhard
+OK 
pass test123
+OK User logged in.
stat
+OK 9 9735
quit
+OK User logged out.

```
telnet localhost 9999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK 
user joendhard
+OK 
pass test123
+OK User logged in.
stat
+OK 9 9735
quit
+OK User logged out.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you observe? You should show input and output of both your program and the telnet session.

Comment: you can see that I call process_pop3() until it returns -1. Afterwards I try to close the connection.

Comment: Is this expected to call process_pop3() with both arguments being the same socket?

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem? Show your actual input and output and the expected output.

Comment: Yes @pbn that is correct.

Comment: @n.m. I have done so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client socket is still open in the parent process. Close it in the parent process after fork.

The socket terminates the connection (by calling `shutdown`) when all file *descriptors* referring to the socket file *description* are closed. You have 2 file *descriptors* here referring to the client socket file *description*.

Comment: Well I have to wait for the childprocess to end for that right?

Comment: @L.Kleinmann Nope, close it immediately after fork in the parent.